# How to style closePath() in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to style the closePath() on my canvas but am at a loss on how to do that, as a matter of fact I would actually like all the lines to have a different style, for this question lets stick to getting different colors. ! As you can see I have a triangle, how can I have differing strokestyles for each line? Here is link to the [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/XwjNxZ)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.moveTo(20, 140); 
ctx.lineTo(120, 10);  
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.lineTo(220, 140); 
ctx.closePath();  
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each segment needs to be coloured.

```js
function qsa(sel,par=document){return par.querySelectorAll(sel)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
 draw();
}

class vec2d
{
 constructor(x=0,y=0)
 {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }
}

function draw()
{
 var verts = [ new vec2d(20,140), new vec2d(120, 10), new vec2d(220,140) ];
 var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

 let can = qsa('canvas')[0];
 let ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 
 var numLineSegs = verts.length;
 for (var lineSegIndex=0; lineSegIndex<numLineSegs; lineSegIndex++)
 {
  var index1 = lineSegIndex;
  var index2 = (lineSegIndex+1)%verts.length;
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = colours[index1];
  ctx.moveTo(verts[index1].x, verts[index1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(verts[index2].x, verts[index2].y);
  ctx.stroke();
 }
 ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: your answer is correct and makes sense but the way I asked it and need it in my context I can't figure it out! How would you change the color of closePath is this context, this is the link to the Code Pen (https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/BeKmeO) where I actually need it!

Comment: I'm looking at your pen and I see a bunch of coloured sine waves. I see that the curves are drawn with different colours, but actually can't quite tell what it is you'd like but don't have. I can't help but wonder if we're in the "X/Y problem" territory at the moment. ClosePath does not have a colour. When you call it, the path created by a previous call which creates a path, is closed and further drawing operations will not affect its size or shape. You then select a colour/pattern and fill or stroke the region enclosed by the path. Sorry, no idea of what you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to have the three lines as three separate paths.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 140); 
ctx.lineTo(120, 10); 
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(120, 10); 
ctx.lineTo(220, 140); 
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(220, 140); 
ctx.lineTo(20, 140); 
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```